# Post thats in Two Categories, only want to display name for one

Tags: customization, theme-development, categories, php, loop

In my Wordpress site I've created, I'm having issues hiding or not displaying one of the category titles I set up. I'll try to explain better.

**Wordpress Admin Side**

I have a post that is in two categories, a "`Work`" & "`Front_Page`"

**Main Page / index.php**

On my main index page, I have 3 features below the header image. One of those features is a "Featured Project". This is how I'm starting the loop...

**Single Project Page**

Now on this page, the visual layout is

Category Name

Which is called `<h2 class="single_category"><?=$cat[0]->name;?></h2>`

Project Title
Large Header Image
Project Desription

**THE PROBLEM!!!**

For whichever post I put in "`Front_Page`", it displays that in the Category Name. I want it to default to the main category.

Is there a way to basically say "if post is in "`front_page`" category, don't display "`front_page`" category as name?

Comment: Please upload your whole theme's sourcecode so it can be better said what your issue is.

Comment: Please don't use shorthand php tags for code samples, not everyone has them enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a bad way that works.

```
<h2 class="single_category"><?
if ($cat[0]->name != "Front_Page") {
    echo $cat[0]->name;
} else {
echo $cat[1]->name;
}
?></h2>
```

Here is a bad way that works and takes up less space.

```
<?php echo ($cat[0]->name != "Front_Page") ? $cat[0]->name : $cat[1]->name; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks cbrandolino, I used the first one, worked like a charm.

Comment: Please don't use shorthand php tags for code samples, not everyone has them enabled.